# How to limit inbound Gmail (ideally) or other free web email to only from contact list (to make it kid-safe)

Tags: gmail, outlook.com

I'm trying to make my kids' (ages 9.5 and 9.5) gmail accounts safer.

Is there a way to limit (filter, etc.) inbound email to only email from folks on their contact list?

Comment: but would you be able to lock the contact list then?

Comment: I'm OK with not locking the contact list. I just want to make sure THEY have initiated all contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the tip from Al Everett, I poked around on Hotmail.

1. Bring up your Hotmail window Click
   on the **Options** drop down menu in
   the upper right corner.
2. Choose **More Options**.
3. Choose Filters and Reporting  Select
   the second option under Junk Email
   Filter: **Exclusive**

Answer (score 3):

Supposedly Hotmail and Yahoo! Mail have this as an option.

You might also consider a service like [ZooBuh](http://zoobuh.com/), which is designed specifically for parental controls over a child's email.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with filters. The problem is that its trivial to remove the filter if you know what you are doing.

1. Create a new filter.
2. In the "From" field type "-(NiceEmail@domain.com) AND -(Nice.EmailTwo@gmail.com)"

   This filter will grab everything that are NOT email addresses that you like.
3. Set the filter to delete those emails.

There are a bunch of potential problems with this, and it is untested. I can confirm that the filter grabs all the non-friendly emails, but it might also grab chats and sent emails. Also, this does not block people from contacting the user through chat.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is actually possible, I've had a dig around the settings on gmail but can't find anything related to this.

I think it is difficult to suggest anything else as we don't know how old your kids are to suggest other ways of managing this...

Comment: Updated question with kids ages: 9.5(twins)